# Is it possible to convert multiple rows into a singular row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to return one row that merges multiple rows so for the example table:

```
ID | VAL1 | VAL2    
1  | v1   | v2    
1  | v3   |v4
```

I would like to return:

```
ID|VAL1|VAL2|VAL1_1|VAL2_1
1 | v1 | v2 | v3   | v4
```

Where ID|VAL1|VAL2|VAL1_1|VAL2_1 are the column headers

I dont believe a pivot can work as the values (v1 etc) can be any value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: do your actual tables also only have two columns to Combine?

Comment: Yes only 2 columns but there may be more than 2 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a dynamic pivot, then you need dynamic SQL.  But, you can do what you want with conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then val1 end) as val1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then val2 end) as val2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then val1 end) as val1_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then val2 end) as val2_1
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

If your rows are ordered in a particular way, then you should modify the `order by`.